# Obtaining a Nest Access Token for sample

Tags: nest-api

I'm just exploring the Nest Developers APIs, so thought I'd start with running the `nestlabs/nest-twitter` sample.

I've hit a couple of problems already!  One is building the source, and the other is obtaining the Nest access token.  I'll address the questions separately, so starting with the Auth problem...

I've created a developer account, and defined a new demo Product.  From there I have used the Authorization URL `https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2?client_id=[myClientId]&state=STATE`, and from my regular Nest account successfully generated an eight character Pincode.

Back to the Product page, I plug the Pincode into the Authorization Token URL

> https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=[myid]&code=[myPincode]&client_secret=[mySecret]&grant_type=authorization_code

The response I get is **"message":"404 Not Found".**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely using an HTTP GET or PUT. Make sure you are using POST.

Comment: Excellent, thanks that's right.  I was using GET, and it works as expected with a switch to POST.